# No of threads on a machine and ThreadPool thread count

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I am new to the concept of threads. I have read that the number of threads for a machine depend on number of cores of the machine i.e. if a machine has 2 cores  it will have 4 threads, 4 cores than 8 threads and so on.
Is my understanding correct that the total number of threads in machine depend on number of cores only? If yes, if we talk about threadpool in .net framework, can a threadpool have more than 16 threads (for an 8 core machine)?

Comment: Not really - Windows 95 used multiple threads at a time when only mainframes used multiple processors. *Every* process has at least one thread and the operating system schedules which thread can run on a core at any time, for how long etc

Answer (score 1):

Threads can be created even in the case of 1 core CPU, i.e. *n* (n>1) number of threads can be running on just 1 core CPU (this is how it was done in old days).

In Multi-threading, what often happens is that Threads are *concurrent* to each other, they compete for one resource, but this is done in such a short time, that they, sort of, seem *virtually parallel* to each other. CPU switching happens in nanoseconds or milliseconds.

Threads *can* run in a really parallel mode, but this means, that at least 2 independent cores of CPU should be at your disposal. Yet, again: scheduling of *what runs where and when* depends on [CPU Scheduling in Operating System](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Ejbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/6_CPU_Scheduling.html).

You should understand that CPU executes a bare binary instructions and it knows nothing more. So, when application is loaded into memory, its threads represent just a bunch of machine-code instructions, which *can be executed* slice by slice, one after another, in particular scheduling, with some halts, or just in parallel. This all (again) depends on the design of OS and CPU.

As said above, often times, several threads may be running on 1 core and CPU Scheduling will be allocating corresponding time slices for each thread, correspondingly threads will compete to each other for one core. In this case, CPU *jumps* from execution some part of instructions from one thread, to execution of some other part in some other thread, and this continues until the threads are alive.

If your CPU has several cores, real parallelism can be achieved, but you [almost] never control this, Operating System and CPU does.

In contrast, see also [how single thread may be running on different cores](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores). As we've said above, execution of some chunk of instructions is scheduled by CPU and OS.

Comment: Thank for the reply @Giorgi. Reading all the answers I have got till now, it has become more complex for me to understand. Let me re-iterate differently now. Are there multiple level of threads in a computer i.e OS level threads, CPU level threads etc? When we talk about creating threads in .Net framework or talk about ThreadPool, which threads are we referring to? What is the limit of these threads in case we are using threading in .Net framework?

Comment: @TechJay all modern versions of Windows can support at least 5000 threads.

Comment: @TechJay there are threads managed by intermediate language, OS Kernel, or etc. but you should not worry about this. This is not programming topic anymore, at least, it's not the programming you should be looking for at this level of knowledge. It's rather architecture and OS level manipulation, which has to do with very low level machine code instructions. The concept of the thread can be thought as an *execution path*. When you enter the method, it has first and last statements, that's the path of that particular method, to go from *first* to *last* (from top to down) in a sequential order.

Comment: @Giorgi, thank you for your efforts. But my question is concerned more of toward .Net framework based programming with threads. So that's the reason I want to know are the ThreadPool threads different from the what we have 2 threads per core?

Comment: @TechJay ThreadPool is just a *pool* of threads which are re-used. You can also Google yourself a little bit and read the basic definitions.

Comment: @Giorgi, the definition of ThreadPool is clear to me already. I just wanted to know how the number of threads in ThreadPool is related to the threads available on a machine. If we have a machine with 4 cores(8 threads), than ThreadPool can have max of 8 threads only?

Comment: Why not try it?  If your processor has 4cores, see how an app behaves with 4 threads in the pool, and again with 400.  If you detect any difference, please call back:)